# How to secure remote APIs for use with tyk?

Tags: api, security, debian, firewall, tyk

All calls are made through the tyk proxy to access the remote api.

How to make the remote api available only through the tyk proxy?

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557962/how-to-secure-remote-api-for-calls-not-coming-from-tyk

Comment: Using a firewall and only allowing traffic from the Tyk IP?

Answer (score 0):

The two options mentioned here [How to secure remote api for calls not coming from tyk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557962/how-to-secure-remote-api-for-calls-not-coming-from-tyk) are very good. Either could work. I don't think there is a setting withing Tyk to limit this. Would have to be done from upstream